# No bonus on stackoverflow when merging accounts with serverfault?

Tags: support

Yesterday I merged my stackoverflow and meta accounts and got 100 point bonuses on both sites. Today I merged my stackoverflow and serverfault accounts and did not get the 100 point bonus on stackoverflow.  Is this how it is supposed to work?  I did the merging (both times) from my stackoverflow account where I have nearly 800 reps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent is to give you +100 on the site where you have 1 rep, if you have at least +200 on another site in the network.

That way you avoid the newbie 1 rep user designation, and can do things like vote, flag offensive, leave comments, and vote down -- because you now have 101 rep instead of 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can only get the association bonus once per site, so since you had already linked your SO account with your Meta account and received your 100-point bonus on SO, you don't get it a second time.